# Is it possible to pd.read_csv data with a date parameter?

Tags: python, pandas

For me, working remotely means accessing big CSV files on a server which take a long time to download to local hard drive.

I've tried to speed this process up using a bit of Python, only reading in particular columns I require. Ideally, however, if I could only read in data for those columns after a date (e.g > 2019-01-04) it would significantly reduce the amount of data.

My existing code for this will read in the total file and then apply a date filter. I'm just wondering if it's possible to apply that date filter to the reading of the file in the first place. I appreciate this might not be possible.

Code e.g...

```
import pandas as pd

fields = ['a','b','c'...]
data1 = pd.read_csv(r'SomeForeignDrive.csv', error_bad_lines=False,usecols=fields)
data1['c']=pd.to_datetime(data1['c'], errors='coerce')
data1.dropna()
data1 = data1[data1['c'] > '2019-01-04']
data1.to_csv(r'SomeLocalDrive.csv')
```

Comment: I would suggest reading only column `'c'` first (`usecols=['c']`), with `parse_dates=['c']`, applying the filter to get the index, then reading the file again with `skiprows=match_index`.

Comment: If that all the operation you are doing then you can simply open the file with`open` check the date condition and append it to new file

Comment: @SayandipDutta does not it means reading the file twice? First we need to iterate the hole csv to get all the rows to determine the required rows, the again?

Comment: @Epsi95 reading the file twice, yes, in a way, but only reading one column would be more time and memory efficient.

Comment: CSV is stored in row wise, so reading a specific column required reading everything, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to read files starting from a specific date but you can use the following workaround. You can read only the column with dates and find the row index where you want to start from. Then you can read the whole file and skip all rows before the start index:

```
df = pd.read_csv('path', usecols=['date'])
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
idx = df[df['date'] > '2019-01-04'].index[0]

df = pd.read_csv('path', skiprows=idx)
```

`read_csv` docs:

> Using this parameter (usecols) results in much faster parsing time and
> lower memory usage.

Comment: Thanks, this is neat. I'll give this a try.